# A noun followed by name

Tags: nouns, names

I'm writing about a painter who depicts his imaginary world that he calls Argondia.

Question:

Consider a sentence, "*His paintings are reflections of an imaginary world Argondia*".
Is the ending "*imaginary world Argondia*" gramatically correct? Or should it be something like "imaginary world **of** Argondia" ?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? Can you give a link?

Comment: @Mitch The OP is the author. See the first sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's grammatical. Why do you think a noun cannot be followed by a name? It means "imaginary world (called) Argondia" -- the (called) is not essential and can be dropped.

Comment: Please see also [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris I disagree. 'The world Argondia' is slightly OK (but weird). 'A world Argondia' sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Mitch You probably have heard about some kind of "Argondia" before, hence the bias.

Comment: You can put a comma after *world* and say you're using an appositive.

Comment: @Kris No, that could not ever be the reason here.

Comment: @Lawrence My son Charlie disagrees.

Comment: @Kris Hmm, Charlie doesn't need a comma, but Argondia feels like it does. Maybe it has to do with the length of the sentence.

Comment: @Lawrence The question is, "can a noun be followed by a name?".

Comment: @Kris Ok :) . Is it a subject/object distinction, I wonder.

Comment: It seems to my experienced (but inexpert) ear that the kind of determiner before the noun makes a big difference.   With an indefinite article, the comma seems to be necessary-ish.   Compare “the Roy Orbison song *Crying*” (OK) and “Roy Orbison’s song *Crying*” (OK) with “a Roy Orbison song *Crying*” (awkward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *world* ***of*** *Argondia* as you suggested will not address the overall issue.

What makes it awkward is the indefinite article.

Consider:

> His paintings are reflections of **the** imaginary world Argondia.

This no longer sounds strange because the specific name is preceded by the definite article.

To keep the *indefinite* article, a different construction would be required in order for it to sound natural. Something like:

> His paintings are reflections of an imaginary world: Argondia.

Comment: You took the words out of my mouth!